# In Scheduling a apex class with constructor

Tags: apex

Please help me with scheduled class code for it.

```
Public class HFCRecord {
    public EMI__c acct ;

list<Detailed_Payment_Schedule__c> lst = new       list<Detailed_Payment_Schedule__c>();
      public integer NoOfdays{get;set;}
      public HFCRecord(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.acct = (EMI__c )stdController.getRecord();
        Id emiId= acct.Id; 

lst = [select id,Payment_Received_Date__c,Clearance__c,Date__c,Net_Payment__c from Detailed_Payment_Schedule__c where EMI_EQI__c =: emiId  order by Payment_Received_Date__c  Desc];
        system.debug('valis'+lst );
           }
    public PageReference  updateEMI() {
    integer i = 0;
    integer da = 0;
    integer dab = 0;
    integer dac = 0;
    integer dad = 0;
    integer  TotalNoOfDays = 360;

        for(Detailed_Payment_Schedule__c d : lst ){

if(d.Clearance__c == true )acct.Last_Payment_Date__c = d.Payment_Received_Date__c;
if(d.Clearance__c == false && d.Date__c <= system.today())i+=1;
if(d.Clearance__c == false && d.Date__c <= system.today())da+=integer.valueOf(d.Net_Payment__c);
if(d.Clearance__c == True && d.Date__c <= system.today())dab+=integer.valueOf(d.Net_Payment__c);
if(d.Clearance__c == False && d.Date__c.day() <= system.today().day()){

       dac+=integer.valueOf(d.Net_Payment__c);
       NoOfdays = (d.Date__c.day() - System.today().day());
       acct.Penal_Charge__c = ((d.Net_Payment__c*(24/100)*1000/TotalNoOfDays)*NoOfdays);
       }
                        }
    system.debug('valisssdf'+i);
    acct.No_of_EMI_Overdue__c = i;
    acct.Overdue_Amount__c = da;
    acct.Amount_Collected__c= dab;
    acct.Penal_Charge__c = dac;
    acct.Total_Amount_Overdue__c = (acct.Penal_Charge__c +           acct.Overdue_Amount__c);
    update acct;
    PageReference pgref = new PageReference('/'+acct.id);
    pgref.setRedirect(true);
    return pgref;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please help in creating scheduler of it as I wrote 

Schedule class : Giving error Constructor not defined: [HFCRecord].<Constructor>() at line 3 column 25 

global class Schedule_HFCRecord implements Schedulable{
   global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        HFCRecord acc = new HFCRecord();
        acc.HFCRecord();
    }
}

Comment: You should consider formatting you question correctly and state you problem and what you tried to solve it so far clearly. Also, creating a minimal exemple for you error is valuable. This will get you closer to getting an answer.

Comment: Hi Wilmerton, above mentioned class : HFCRecord is the class i wrote. Now i am trying to schedule it. Pease check if i can schedule it and if schedule than how...... Thanks

Comment: I'm not here to answer, I'm just giving you an advice. Read some popular (upvoted) questions in order to better understand how to improve your question.

Comment: What do you mean by a "scheduled class"?

Comment: Re your first comment, are you still getting an error? If so, please edit that into your questions - important information in the comments is likely to be overlooked

Answer (score 0):

In order to schedule apex code in Salesforce, you need a global class that implements the 'Schedulable' interface.  You can then schedule it through the UI (Setup->Apex Classes), or with anonymous apex.  Example code below:

```
global class Schedulable_ClassExample implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
         HFCRecord hfcRecord = new HFCRecord();
         hfcRecord.DoStuff();
    }
}
```